# Boolean condition evaluated inside for loop performance

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

I have two loops. I don't understand why the first one runs faster than my second one. Can you explain as simply as possible?

First:

```
for (int x1=0;x1<1000;x1++){
   for(int x2=0;x2<1000;x2++){
      if(x1<500){
         a[x2+x1*1000]=100;
      }
   }
}
```

Second:

```
bool cond;
for (int x1=0; x1<1000; x1++) {
    cond = x1<500;
    for(int x2=0; x2<1000; x2++){
        if(cond){
            a[x2+x1*1000] = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

(I simplified my code)

Comment: How much slower/faster? Show actual benchmarks. If the difference is minor, it may be almost everything (including inefficiencies caused by the OS you cannot influence) and can be neglected in good conscience.

Comment: in my code this expression cause %30 slow down of the code

Comment: Show actual benchmarks. But admittedly, it's not minor.

Comment: sorry i am not very experienced code writer, i just wanted to improve my code run time. i cite the deterioration in time for one loop

Comment: @AyleanClaraGrandieur Please show how you benchmarked these codes. How did you measure actually?

Comment: I think you failed to control for some other source of difference.  There are lots of reasons the opposite performance difference (that you likely expected) will not occur, but no good explanation for the difference you report.  So you made a mistake.  (An optimizer could recognize the major optimization one way and not the other, but I still don't believe the results)

Comment: Code timing is very software/hardware-specific. Thus, you need to tell us which tool (and possibly which machine, OS, etc.) you used.

Comment: Well, it makes sense that doing a comparison 1,000 times is faster then doing it 1,000,000 times.

Comment: my machine is windows 10, i use microsoft visual c++ 2010 edition

Comment: BTW, using directly `500` as `x1` limit is cleaner and faster.

Comment: dj actually it is the opposite, that makes me wonder.

Comment: It might just be because of simplifying the example but if you are only ever going to do something while `x1` is less than 500 why not have `for (int x1=0;x1<500;x1++)`?

Comment: @jarod thank you, my actual code is a bit more complex, i simplified the code, but i understand your point

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realize the first loop is the faster one.

Comment: Are optimizations turned on compiling both sets of code? If not, the results are pretty useless; with compiler optimizations off, both sets of code will do dumb things (I suspect with compiler optimizations turned all the way up, they'll actually behave pretty similarly).

Comment: Any decent optimizer should promote either test out of the inner loop, so there should be no performance difference.  A look at the generated asm code would be the best way to see if the optimizer were somehow confused by one version and not the other.

Comment: I dont get the same result: http://ideone.com/eQ0Txj

Comment: @Ben shouldn't `a` be of the size `500000`?  If `x1` can be 499 then `a[x2+x1*1000]` => `a[x2+499000]`

Comment: Maybe the first one is an known pattern for compiler whereas the second one break this recognition.

Comment: @NathanOliver True, but this doesnt change the result: http://ideone.com/eQ0Txj

Comment: i update the question, with my original code

Comment: @Ben OK.  Just wanted to make sure the UB wasn't affecting anything.

Comment: with clang 3.7.0 -std=c++11 -O2, they both compile to absolutely identical assembly: https://goo.gl/TovE0d. By "they" I mean the original, simpler code samples (you changed it while I checked).

Comment: In the updated code, did you compile with optimization turned up? If not, the first one seems like it should run (slightly) faster, as it avoids retesting the same thing over and over. That said, without optimizations turned up, the results are meaningless.

Comment: i didnt turn on optimization, then i should learn about the subject. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is when you use

```
if(x1<500){
      a[x2+x1*1000]=100;
          }
```

you actually are using a direct method in which values are compared and work is done but when you use

```
if(cond) { 
  a[x2+x1*1000] = 100;
         }
```

then it first calculates the answer of " cond "  then applies the if condition , being more specific you can just take it as if cond is a function call and if(x1<500) is a simple comparison within main() .
Hopefully you got your answer and if you want to know anything else about this topic tell me :)